# Send IGMP multicast group leave from Linux command line

Tags: linux, multicast, igmp

I would like to simply send a IGMP multicast group leave from my client on ethernet port, for example, eth2, to the switch in order to leave, for example, multicast group 239.1.2.3. From the Linux command line.

I have not been able to find any simple examples that does just that. I have been down rabbit holes with Socat and Scapy. Both seem overkill for something so trivial. And I've not managed to find an example for them either. Even an example with those would get me a step closer to trying out the idea.

I was hoping to find some tool offering a simple command along the lines of:

`igmp-leave -i eth2 239.1.2.3`

(This is for testing a ST2022-7 to cause a drop in one of the essences on purpose to simulate a network error. I can't take down the network interface or modify anything on the switch. This detail is unimportant but I included it for context).